# How to use steam controller as a game controller outside of steam

Tags: input, steam, game-controller, input-device

I am playing a game that is only available in the EpicGames store and i would very much like to play it using a gamepad. But the only gamepad i own is a steam controller and it always emulates keyboard and mouse inputs when outside of steam (in 'desktop mode') which does not allow for more than one axis input (the mouse).

How do i use the steam controller as a controller-input outside of steam? Any solution allowing me to use the axis inputs of the stick, the trackpads AND the shoulder triggers (which means only emulating mouse axis does not suffice) would solve my problem without emulating a full e.g. xbox-controller.

Comment: Have you tried linking the Epic games to Steam and opening it from there?

Comment: I'll try doing that as soon as i'm home

Comment: It worked, how did i not think of that! You want to post this as an answer?

Comment: That's great, will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially linking Epic games to Steam and opening it from there should do it.

Refer [here](https://www.resetera.com/threads/psa-this-is-how-you-set-up-steam-input-for-epic-games-launcher.119351/post-21169485) for instructions.